# Difference between Node 8 and Node 10 on handling streams and stream events?

Tags: node.js

In Node 10.24.1, the stream from downloading a file (readStream) with axios it’s changed to paused if I am adding this to monitor the memory at certain events before piping to a Writable Stream.

```
readStream.on('data', (data) => {
  process.memoryUsage();
})
.on('error', (error) => {
  console.log('err: ' + error);
 })
.on('readable', () => {
  console.log('stream state:  ' + readStream.isPaused());
 })
```

It just stops at the ‘readable’ event and shows me readStream is paused and does not write the file locally:

```
readStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('C:\\file.mp4'));
```

If I remove the code with the events and just pipe the file, it works.

However, in Node 8.17.1, the data flows through and I could see the memory usage whenever it receives data chunks and continues writing the file locally.

I am trying to figure our what is the difference and what I am doing wrong. I've read the documentation and gone through various resources but still don't get it.
I would appreciate any type of help in trying to figure this out and understand streams and events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node v10 documentation explicitly states the following:

- *Adding a 'readable' event handler automatically makes the stream stop flowing.*
- *If both 'readable' and 'data' are used at the same time, 'readable' takes precedence in controlling the flow, i.e. 'data' will be emitted only when stream.read() is called.*

So that should clear it up as far as the observed behaviour here with v10.

Not sure about the exact expected behaviour for v8 though. Note that either way, the `data` and `readable` events are a bit conflicting in nature in the first place - one results in data being automatically pushed out of the stream, the other in data being pulled on demand. So maybe the safest bet is to not mix them that way.